# Tracing error in database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, one-to-many

I have a client server program and the server checks if the client opened the right application. If not then it will display some warning. It should only open three applications along with the right one. I am planning to put the data of opened application and the users hostname into the database. There will be two table, hostnametable and processtable.
Example:

hostnametable

```
hostname_id | hostname
------------------------
      1     | Guest1
      2     | Guest2
      3     | Guest3
```

processtable

```
id | processID | processName | processExe | processPath     | hostname_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |    4332   |  C# Basic   |  adobe.exe | C:/Users/Adm... |      2      
2  |    5400   |  PHP 101    |  ppt.exe   | C:/Users/Adm... |      2      
3  |    0943   |  Notice     |notepad.exe | C:/Users/Adm... |      1      
4  |    8932   |  Java 101   |  adobe.exe | C:/Users/Adm... |      3      
5  |    7608   |  Certific   |  word.exe  | C:/Users/Adm... |      1      
6  |    0101   |  Aliens     |  ppt.exe   | C:/Users/Adm... |      1      
7  |    8200   |  Progress   |  excel.exe | C:/Users/Adm... |      3
```

Once the client open a new application, [hostname,processID,processName, processExe, processPath] will be sent in the server. The server will

> -check if the hostname exist by getting the hostname count,
>
> -if yes then it will select the hostname_id and
>
> -insert it in a new table along with the other data.

If not

> -then a new hostname is inserted in the hostname table
>
> -it will select the hostname_id
>
> -and insert the data

This is a one-to-many relationship so in the later part I need to retrieve it for output display and validation.
My problem is I've debugged the database part of the code step by step but when I run them as a whole it will catch an error at the very end of the process. In here it will automatically go to

```
catch { output.Text += "\nERROR THREE\n "; }
```

Here is my code.

```
 using (MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (exeFile == openedFile)
                    {
                        listBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                        listBox1.Items.Add(machineName + " has opened the right file.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string count1 = "SELECT COUNT(hostName) FROM hostnametable;";
                        string gethostname_id = "SELECT INTO chtbuster.hostnametable(hostName_id) WHERE hostName=?machineName";
                        string insert_pt = "INSERT INTO chtbuster.processtable(processID,processFileName,processName,processPath,hostName_id) VALUES (@processID, @fileName, @exeFile, @filePath, " + gethostname_id + ");";
                        string insert_ht = "INSERT INTO chtbuster.hostnametable(hostName_id) VALUES(@machineName);";
                        //query for else condition 1 is at the top

                        listBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        listBox1.Items.Add(machineName + " has opened " + exeFile);
                        conDataBase.Open();

                        MySqlCommand cmd1Database = new MySqlCommand(count1, conDataBase);
                        cmd1Database.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

                        Int32 ifexist = (Int32)cmd1Database.ExecuteScalar();
                        if(ifexist>0)
                        {
                           MySqlCommand cmd2Database = new MySqlCommand(gethostname_id, conDataBase);
                            machineName = (string)cmd1Database.ExecuteScalar(); 
                            cmd2Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("?machineName", machineName);

                            MySqlCommand cmd3Database = new MySqlCommand(insert_pt, conDataBase);

                              try
                              {
                                  cmd3Database.Parameters.Clear();
                                  cmd3Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("@processID", processID);
                                  cmd3Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineName", machineName);
                                  cmd3Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", fileName);
                                  cmd3Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("@exeFile", exeFile);
                                  cmd3Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filePath", filePath);
                                  cmd3Database.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                  cmd2Database.ExecuteReader();

                               }
                              catch (Exception ex)
                              {
                                  output.Text += "\n1" + (ex.Message);
                              } 
                        }

                        else
                        {
                           MySqlCommand cmd4Database = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
                           MySqlCommand cmd5Database = new MySqlCommand(insert_ht, conDataBase);

                            try
                              {
                                  cmd5Database.Parameters.Clear();
                                  cmd5Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("@processID", processID);
                                  cmd5Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineName", machineName);
                                  cmd5Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", fileName);
                                  cmd5Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("@exeFile", exeFile);
                                  cmd5Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filePath", filePath);
                                  cmd4Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineName", machineName);
                                  cmd4Database.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                  cmd5Database.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                  conDataBase.Close();

                               }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                output.Text += "\n2" + (ex.Message);
                            } 
                      }    
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    output.Text += "\n3" + (ex.Message);
                } 
            }
```

Comment: So you aren't actually looking to see what the exceptions are?  Just that *something* happened?  It'll be hard to determine why "ERROR THREE" is happening if we don't know what the exception is that caused it.

Comment: You also have a logic error, if I'm reading this right:  you close `conDataBase` after `cmd3Database.ExecuteNonQuery`, but then you try to run `cmd1Database.ExecuteNonQuery` later and then close `conDataBase` again.  It will already be closed.

Comment: As @Ann L. said, you are trying to close the conDataBase connection multiple times. This will throw an exception. In the future, I suggest you catch (Exception ex) and then post the exception message (at least) here when you have a problem. It's much easier to see what is causing an exception when you know what the exception is.

Comment: @AnnL. Thanks for the quick response. I have edited my code and placed catch (Exception ex) and it gives me "Specified cast is not valid." on the third catch. How can I fix this?

Comment: the "Specified cast is not valid." is probably on ExecuteScalar()

Comment: hello @Ann L. is there a way to check if my data exists in the database? I've only tried doing database in PHP and I know my logic is right, it's just that the syntax in C# is quite complicated. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @charlie9495  Do you mean, query the database server outside of C#, just to check that the data exists (and your query works)?  Yes.  If you are using Visual Studio, this link may help.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272679(VS.103).aspx

Comment: @charlie9495 As for the "Specified cast is not valid", I am putting that in an answer because I want to include a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you still have a logic problem:

```
 MySqlCommand cmd1Database = new MySqlCommand(count1, conDataBase);
 cmd1Database.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

 Int32 ifexist = (Int32)cmd1Database.ExecuteScalar();
 if(ifexist>0)
 {
       MySqlCommand cmd2Database = new MySqlCommand(gethostname_id, conDataBase);
       machineName = (string)cmd1Database.ExecuteScalar();
```

You haven't changed the `CommandText` property of `cmd1Database` since the first time you ran it.  So it's going to run the same query, the one specified in `count1`.

That will return an `Int32`.  That can't be directly converted to a `string`, as you are doing with your `(string)cmd1Database.ExecuteScalar();`.

### With regard to the "Specified cast is not valid":

Now, I don't know the quirks of `MySqlCommand`.  But here's a quote from the documentation for what I assume is the base class (.NET's `System.Data.Common.DbCommand`):

> If the first column of the first row in the result set is not found, a
>   null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) is returned. If the value in
>   the database is null, the query returns DBNull.Value.

([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx))

Depending on which `ExecuteScalar` is causing the problem, you might be facing slightly different situations.  If there are no rows being returned, your `ExecuteScalar` will return `Null`.  That can't be converted to `Int32`.  You have to deal with it like this:

```
 int rowCount = 0;
 object result = cmd1Database.ExecuteScalar();
 if(result != null)
 {
     rowCount = (Int32) result;
 }
```

If there's data, but the value is `Null` in the database, the value returned will be the rather peculiar type [DBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx).  This won't convert to any other type (except `Object`).  So you wind up doing something like this:

```
 object result = cmd1Database.ExecuteScalar(); 
 if(!DBNull.Value.Equals(result))
 {
      machineName = (string) result;
 }
```